# Three20: import only TTPhotoViewController

Tags: iphone, three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

I've an Xcode project that use Three20 Library for iPhone apps, but I use only TTPhotoViewController!
It's possible to import only this features?
My app before Three20 was 430 KB, now it's 2,4 MB :'(
thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. Forget Three20. It might have been a more viable solution had it been broken out into separate components as you're suggesting, but alas, it was not.

Try this: https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser

Best regards.

Comment: +1,@Matt Long,  Nice tutorial for Photo library. Previously i have used Three20 and my apps was in the appStore now. Does apple allowed for used this "KTPhotoBrowser" package. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Kirby Turner, the developer, mentions on the github readme that he has apps in the app store that use his library.

Answer (score 1):

you may take a look at this then, it's just an essential photo-gallery, easier to install and use:

[mwaterfall-MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)